# installation for spark 2.1.0 with Ambari 2.4.2.0

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, cluster-computing, hortonworks-data-platform, ambari

I am relatively new on cluster installations for Spark along with Ambari. Recently, I got a task for installing Spark 2.1.0 on a cluster which pre-installed Ambari with Spark 1.6.2 with HDFS & YARN 2.7.3.

My task is to have Spark 2.1.0 installed since it is the newest version with better compacity with RSpark and more. I searched over the internet for couple days, only found some installation guide on either AWS or Spark 2.1.0 alone.

such as following:
http://data-flair.training/blogs/install-deploy-run-spark-2-x-multi-node-cluster-step-by-step-guide/
and http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/building-spark.html.

But none of them mentioning the interference of different versions of Spark. Since I need to keep this cluster running, I would like to know some potential threat for the cluster.

Is there some proper way to do this installation? Thanks a lot!

Comment: What ambari stack are you using and which version? HDP, IOP, PHD, etc? Do you want Spark2 to be managed by Ambari?

Comment: yes, I would like to have Spark2 managed by Ambari. I am new to Ambari actually, not sure where I can find all those versions of HDP, IOP, PHD, could you show me a way? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Log into ambari, on the top right click the Admin button, choose Stacks and Version, click the Versions tab. It will tell you what stack and what version you are currently using.

Comment: It is using the following:
HDP - 2.5.3.0,
HDFS - 2.7.3
YARN - 2.7.3
MapReduce2 - 2.7.3
Tez - 0.7.0
Hive - 1.2.1000
Pig - 0.16.0
ZooKeeper - 3.4.6
Ambari Infra - 0.1.0
Ambari Metrics - 0.1.0
SmartSense - 1.3.1.0-136
Spark - 1.6.2
Slider - 0.91.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to have your SPARK2 installation managed by Ambari then SPARK2 must be provisioned by Ambari.

HDP 2.5.3 does **NOT** support Spark 2.1.0, it does however come with a technical preview of Spark 2.0.0.

Your options are:

- Install Spark 2.1.0 manually and not have it managed by Ambari
- Use Spark 2.0.0 instead of Spark 2.1.0 which is provided by HDP 2.5.3
- Use a different stack. ie. IBM Open Platform (IOP) 4.3, slated to release in 2017, it will ship with Spark 2.1.0 support. You can get started using it today with the [technical preview release](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSPT3X_4.3.0/com.ibm.swg.im.infosphere.biginsights.product.doc/doc/whatsnew.html).
- Upgrade HDP (2.6) which supports Spark 2.1.
- Extend the HDP 2.5 stack to support Spark 2.1.0. You can see how to customize and extend ambari stacks on the [wiki](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/AMBARI/Stacks+and+Services). This would let you used Spark 2.1.0 and have it managed by ambari. However, this would be a lot of work to implement and being that you're new to Ambari it would be rather difficult.

Comment: Thank you so much! This really showed me a way to go, you know there is nothing really relevant on google search. :)

Comment: Also, I would like to know how hard it will be to install Spark 2.1.0 manually and not managed by Ambari. Will that action ruin the Ambari system? Will the Spark 2.1.0 conflicted with Spark 1.6.0 in previous installation inside of Ambari Packages?

Comment: I know it's possible to have them co-exist as Cloudera does it. But I'm unsure of what effort would be involved to get them to co exist on an Ambari provisioned platform without causing issues. There is some documentation for HDP with working on a cluster that has Spark 1.6 and Spark 2.0 installed: https://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/HDP2/HDP-2.5.0/bk_spark-component-guide/content/spark-choose-version.html

Comment: Do you in case know any reliable Spark 2.1.0 installation guide? I have seen so many different versions of guidance, but most of them required an empty system. And again, thanks so much!